# gzip compression on wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, gzip

I'm trying to set compression on wordpress site. Googled like a hundred of atricles, tried everything i could find.
Tried plugins, tried modifying .htaccess file in a multiple ways.
Like this:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

# Removing browser bugs for older browsers
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
```

Like this:

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
</ifModule>
```

Even like this:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE "application/atom+xml" \
    "application/javascript" \
    "application/json" \
    "application/ld+json" \
    "application/manifest+json" \
    "application/rdf+xml" \
    "application/rss+xml" \
    "application/schema+json" \
    "application/vnd.geo+json" \
    "application/vnd.ms-fontobject" \
    "application/x-font-ttf" \
    "application/x-javascript" \
    "application/x-web-app-manifest+json" \
    "application/xhtml+xml" \
    "application/xml" \
    "font/eot" \
    "font/opentype" \
    "image/bmp" \
    "image/svg+xml" \
    "image/vnd.microsoft.icon" \
    "image/x-icon" \
    "text/cache-manifest" \
    "text/css" \
    "text/html" \
    "text/javascript" \
    "text/plain" \
    "text/vcard" \
    "text/vnd.rim.location.xloc" \
    "text/vtt" \
    "text/x-component" \
    "text/x-cross-domain-policy" \
    "text/xml"

    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        AddEncoding gzip              svgz
    </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

I checked phpinfo settings, and modules are activated

```
gzip compression    enabled

_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"] gzip, deflate
```

But as a result - the only gzipped files are google fonts and cdn js libraries. Everything from inside the site the same.

Any ideas what i'm missing?

Trying to make this one -

```
http://terminaltuning.ru/
http://kurgan.terminaltuning.ru/
http://tyumen.terminaltuning.ru/
```

Comment: and you've set `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` ?

Answer (score 0):

turned out the issue was in nginx configuration

its was turned on

```
gzip on
```

but types were commented

```
# gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
```